# Compile apk using ionic 3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, ionic3

I'm trying to compile my app on ionic and it shows me this error.

```
PS D:\Trabajo\Ionic\Proyecto\miProyecto> ionic cordova build --release android
    Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
    [15:03:39]  build dev started ...
    [15:03:39]  clean started ...
    [15:03:39]  clean finished in 15 ms
    [15:03:39]  copy started ...
    [15:03:40]  deeplinks started ...
    [15:03:40]  deeplinks finished in 122 ms
    [15:03:40]  transpile started ...
    [15:03:50]  transpile finished in 10.33 s
    [15:03:50]  preprocess started ...
    [15:03:50]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms
    [15:03:50]  webpack started ...
    [15:03:51]  copy finished in 11.48 s
    [15:04:01]  webpack finished in 11.26 s
    [15:04:01]  sass started ...
    Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
    [15:04:04]  sass finished in 2.18 s
    [15:04:04]  postprocess started ...
    [15:04:04]  postprocess finished in 45 ms
    [15:04:04]  lint started ...
    [15:04:04]  build dev finished in 24.48 s
    > cordova build android --release
    [15:04:09]  lint finished in 5.17 s
    ANDROID_HOME=D:\Android\androidsdk
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_121
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Exception in thread "main"
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:77)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:43)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:43)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
    (node:8548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:77)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:43)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:43)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)

    PS D:\Trabajo\Ionic\Proyecto\miProyecto>
```

This is my config.xml file:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>miProyecto</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="1.1.19" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="^2.6.2" />
</widget>
```

Use: windows 10 x64, ionic v3.20.0, cordova v8.0.0, npm v3.10.10, node v6.11.3, gradle v4.1. I am also working behind a proxy. The problem seems to be in the gradle but it is well configured with its environment variables to point to the gradle file that I have downloaded. Any ideas?

Comment: Try: ionic cordova build android --prod

Comment: gives the same error mohsen solhnia

Comment: npm  clear cashe -- force, cordova clean, ionic cordova platform rm android

Comment: Hi @FelixAMarreroPentón did you fix this issue? I am getting this error and not able to get a solution.

Comment: @AkshayaJeevan i am using Flutter now